# Deploy golang martini HTTPS on Heroku server

Tags: ssl, heroku, go, martini

I am trying to deploy an HTTPS web side on Heroku using [Golang-martini](https://github.com/go-martini/martini).

Here is the list I already done:

- I already enable SSL endpoint in Heroku. (it is paid plugin services)
- I already purchase my CA certificate key and it could be deploy Heroku. So, `heroku certs` shows: (note: the company name/endpoint address change)

  ---

  Endpoint  ||                 Common Name(s)  ||    Expires        ||       Trusted

  ---

  xxx.herokussl.com || server.sample.com ||  2016-05-25 23:59 UTC  || True

And here is my code sample in Golang.

```
m := martini.Classic()
martini.Env = martini.Prod
m.Use(secure.Secure(secure.Options{
    SSLRedirect: false,
}))


//Because I want to keep HTTP and HTTPs enable.
go func() {
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":"+os.Getenv("PORT"), m); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
}()

// HTTPS: 
if err := http.ListenAndServeTLS(":443", "server.crt", "server.key", m); err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
```

Here are the my Questions:

- If I set the `ListenAndServeTLS` port in 8443 (or something else) it will show error when I trying to test with `curl -vI https://server.sample.com`. It will show error as:

  "curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain"
- If I set the `ListenAndServeTLS` port to 443, it will show:

  "listen tcp :443: bind: permission denied"

Please advise how I deploy HTTPs with Go-martini on Heroku, thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app won't serve HTTPS if you are deploying to Heroku. The SSL connection will be terminated at the load balancers of Heroku and plain HTTP traffic will be forwarded to your application.

So all you have to do is to listen on HTTP on the Port from the environment.

Comment: Hi inf, Thanks for reply. But I found it works well in Rails on Heroku.  http://readysteadycode.com/howto-setup-ssl-with-rails-and-heroku

Comment: @EvanLin I have no experience with Rails but I guess that all that setting does is to redirect http requests to https and sets HSTS plus maybe some other stuff.

Comment: Thank you, I will check with Heroku, if it is true.

Comment: Hi inf, Confirm with Heroku, it is expect. 

"Yep the SSL termination is done well before the dyno at the SSL endpoint add-on. Inside the dyno you only have to bind to one port and speak HTTP. No SSL required in-app."